# How can I go about passing an ApiParam to a validator of another variable?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator

I'm in a bit of a pickle, and not sure what I should do beyond just giving up making this Validator as comprehensive as I'd like it to be. I have an endpoint that looks a lot like this:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/v1/operation/{actionType}")
    public void operation(
        @ApiParam(value = "type", required = true, allowableValues = "retry-all, retry-parquet, re-drop")
        @PathVariable("actionType") RetryActionType actionType,

        @Null @RequestBody @Valid RetryDto retryDto
    ) throws Exception {...}
```

Now, the `@Valid` annotation behind `retryDto` is a pretty fleshed out validator that makes sure the `retryDto` is correct. The problem is, with recent developments and extra features added, the validity of the retryDto now depends on `actionType`.

I am pretty lost on how to include `actionType` in the `retryDto`. My constraints are as follows:

1. I cannot change this endpoint. I cannot, for example, make `actionType` *not* an ApiParam, nor can I make `retryDto` *not* a RequestBody. I don't think so, at least. If you can think of an intelligent way to keep the endpoint (`"/v1/operation/{actionType}"`) the same, accepting `{actionType}` as an ApiParam *and* a request body but, say, they can both be made into one object to look something like this:

   ```
   @PutMapping(value = "/v1/operation/{actionType}")
   public void operation(
           @??? @??? @??? NewTypeThatIsActionTypeAndRetryDto x
       ) throws Exception {...}
   ```

   I would be fine with that. Again, the `NewType...` must be able to accept the ApiParam and the RequestBody. Doubt that's possible, but I'm no expert.
2. I can't make clients include the `actionType` in the RequestBody of retryDto. That does not mean that if, say, any of you know a way I can automatically add the `actionType` to the `retryDto` that that would be unacceptable. In other clearer words, I can change `retryDto` to accept an `actionType` "automatically". Should go without saying that my validator has to be able to see it, of course.

I think that's it. I was hoping I could somehow automatically add `actionType` to `retryDto`. Maybe there is some way I can make `@Valid` accept a variable as a param? I'm pretty sure annotations must take constants... but maybe there is some way?

Maybe something else entirely? Would love to hear back. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I figured it out a couple of hours ago. Inside of my function, I was calling another function that actually consumed the `retryDto` parameter. I placed the validator in the definition of that function and it worked! I foolishly thought it would only work inside the api function, but was wrong.

```
@PutMapping(value = "/v1/operation/{actionType}")
    public void operation(
        @ApiParam(value = "type", required = true, allowableValues = "retry-all, retry-parquet, re-drop")
        @PathVariable("actionType") RetryActionType actionType,

        @Null @RequestBody RetryDto retryDto
    ) throws Exception
    {
     ...
            retryDto.setActionType(actionType);
            retryService.retry(actionType, retryDto);
     }
```

```
public void retry(RetryActionType actionType, @Valid RetryDto retryDto)
```

That worked! Ended up changing the retryDto to include that, so that was the only caveat. Maybe not a true fix and if anyone has any better ideas, go for it.